# "Cross-classification and tabulation" tool is not outputting a table

Tags: qgis-processing, saga, qgis-3

In QGIS3 I’m trying to use SAGA’s "Cross-classification and tabulation” tool from the processing toolbox, and based on the documentation (http://www.saga-gis.org/saga_tool_doc/6.3.0/grid_analysis_13.html) and this example I found (https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264242/117412) I’m expecting it to output both a grid and a table. But every time I’ve tried it (with various inputs) it only outputs a grid. And as the below screenshot shows, it doesn’t even show an output parameter for the table.

[image: ui of cross-classification and tabulation tool in QGIS3]

So why isn’t the "Cross-classification and tabulation” tool outputting a table?

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Maybe it's now different with the new version (I use 3.6), but at first I also didn't get an output table. What helped: save file to... and then choose *dbf format, not shapefile