# Calculate % agriculture and % forestry cover across each 10km square of the UK

Tags: qgis, land-cover, forest-ecology, agriculture, wildlife-ecology

I am working on investigating the relationship between agricultural intensity and the diversity of birds. I have a shapefile of a map that splits the UK into 10km squares and for each square I need to calculate the % that is used for agriculture and % that is natural forest.

I have the program QGIS as I have not used ARC much before. Can anyone simply explain and help me with how to do this? I have access to land cover and crop maps too.

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/321910/81764

Comment: If you have an accurate land cover map you are in business. The following link shows how to use the ArcGIS "Tabulate Area" approach in QGIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/264242/8104